# Can I highlight activated buttons in blender python script?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I've been working on a Add on for my job for almost 3 months now (I have never programmed in my life i didn't know what i was doing)- It lets anyone create their own dental model to print and practice on and i was really happy with it but for the last 2 weeks i've been completely stuck- this is what it looks like so far:
[image]

Each number stands for a position on the jaw, it can either be:
B- Blank,
S- a stump, or
T- a tooth
only one button can be active at a time so nothing overlaps, BUT i really want the last pressed button to be highlighted so you can see what you already did.
I figured a radio button system would be perfect for this but i just can't do it, what am i doing wrong?

This is what the code for one row usually looks like:

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout

    row = layout.row(align=True)
    row.label(text="11")
    row.operator("object.delete_operator", text="B").object_name = "11"
    row.operator("object.subdivision_operator", text="S").object_name = "11"
    row.operator("object.custom_operator", text="T").object_name = "11"
```

Then i modified it

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout

    row = layout.row()
    row.label(text="11")
    layout.prop(context.scene, "my_enum_property", expand=True)
    if context.scene.my_enum_property == "B":
        row.operator("object.delete_operator", text="B").object_name = "11"
    elif context.scene.my_enum_property == "S":
        row.operator("object.subdivision_operator", text="S").object_name = "11"
    elif context.scene.my_enum_property == "T":
        row.operator("object.custom_operator", text="T").object_name = "11"
```

and added

```
enum_items = [
("B", "B", "Delete Operator"),
("S", "S", "Subdivision Operator"),
("T", "T", "Custom Operator")] 
bpy.types.Scene.my_enum_property = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
name="Options",
description="Select an option",
items=enum_items)
```

[image]
But then somehow a dublicate button appears and i can select all buttons but only once i press the dublicate something actually happens?

I'm so exhausted there is so much i still want to do here but i just feel burnt out- any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: You are using an EnumProperty to draw Operators to the layout.

```
if context.scene.my_enum_property == "B":   # if enum = value
    row.operator("object.delete_operator", text="B").object_name = "11"   # draw this operator
```

In this case I would use only operators in the layout that can be highlighted with attribute `depress` ([Manual](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.operator)).
The enum is used in the background, changed in operator classes, to highlight the layout operator elements.

```
import bpy

### UI                      
class TEST_PT_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = 'TEST_PT_Panel'
    bl_label = "Test Panel"                      
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "TEST"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row(align=True)

        row.label(text="11")

        row.operator("object.delete_operator", text="B",
                      depress = True if context.scene.my_enum_property == "B" else False  # this highlights op if enum = 'B'
                    ).object_name = "11"

        row.operator("object.subdivision_operator", text="S",
                      depress = True if context.scene.my_enum_property == "S" else False  # this highlights op if enum = 'S'
                    ).object_name = "11"

        row.operator("object.custom_operator", text="T",
                      depress = True if context.scene.my_enum_property == "T" else False  # this highlights op if enum = 'T'
                    ).object_name = "11"

### OPERATORS
class OBJECT_OT_Delete(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = 'object.delete_operator'
    bl_label = "Delete Operator"
    object_name : bpy.props.StringProperty()
    def execute(self, context):

        context.scene.my_enum_property = "B"  # set enum to "B" to highlight op in layout     

        # control output
        print("Object:" , self.object_name, " / Operator:", self.bl_idname)
        return {'FINISHED'}        

class OBJECT_OT_Subdivision(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = 'object.subdivision_operator'
    bl_label = "Subdivision Operator"
    object_name : bpy.props.StringProperty()
    def execute(self, context):

        context.scene.my_enum_property = "S"  # set enum to "S" to highlight op in layout 

        # control output
        print("Object:" , self.object_name, " / Operator:", self.bl_idname)
        return {'FINISHED'}   

class OBJECT_OT_Custom(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = 'object.custom_operator'
    bl_label = "Custom Operator"
    object_name : bpy.props.StringProperty()
    def execute(self, context):

        context.scene.my_enum_property = "T"  # set enum to "T" to highlight op in layout 

        # control output
        print("Object:" , self.object_name, " / Operator:", self.bl_idname)
        return {'FINISHED'} 

### REGISTRY
classes = (
    TEST_PT_Panel, 
    OBJECT_OT_Delete,
    OBJECT_OT_Subdivision,
    OBJECT_OT_Custom,       
    )

def register():
    from bpy.utils import register_class
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)

    enum_items = [
    ("0", "", ""),   # nothing selected
    ("B", "B", "Delete Operator"),
    ("S", "S", "Subdivision Operator"),
    ("T", "T", "Custom Operator")] 
    bpy.types.Scene.my_enum_property = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
    name="Options",
    description="Select an option",
    items=enum_items)
            
def unregister():
    from bpy.utils import unregister_class
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        unregister_class(cls)
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: OMG, TYSM! You must have put so much time and effort into this. I can't thank you enough.  Just one more question if I'm allowed: I'm using 'import os,' and I have a couple of file paths in my script specific to my PC (I haven't figured out how to make actually downloadable add-ons yet). When I try to update my operators to your script and add the 'import os', the highlight permanently locks on the first button. Do you think that's because the paths are causing issues? Or could my operators be too complicated to make this work?

Comment: Oh, I forgot. This has nothing to do with the filepaths, regardless of whether you are using module `os`. If an enum property is initialized, the first item is set by default if attribute `default` not specified. Add an enum item at first position, e.g. `("0", "", "")` to unmark all layout.operators. Now you can use `context.scene.my_enum_property = "0"` anywhere to reset the highlighted layout.operators. See line 80 in edited script.